# Django BooleanField if statement doesnt return content

Tags: django

For some reason when checking to see if BooleanField post.featured is true I get no output. If I remove that it works fine but not as I intend.

```py
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for post in object_list%}
        {% if post.featured is True %}<!-- This post.featured is BooleanField -->
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <div class="carousel-item active">
            {% else %}
                <div class="carousel-item">
            {% endif %}
                    <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
                        <h1 class="display-4 font-italic">{{ post.title }}</h1>
                        <p class="lead my-3">{{ post.hook }}</p>
                        <p class="lead mb-0">
                           <a href="{% url 'article-details' post.pk %}" class="text-white fw-bold">
                               Continue reading...
                           </a>
                        </p>           
                    </div>
                </div>
        {% endif %}<!-- and this -->
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Heres how it looks like when not checking if post.featured == true:

[image: Working]

However, content doesnt render with `{% if post.featured is True %}` or `{% if post.featured %}`

Can someone please explain what im doing wrong

EDIT:
Submiting my view:

```py
class Home(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

Comment: Share your view. You should not filter in the template, but in the view.

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Django. To elaborate a bit, I've got a carousel at the top of my page with featured blog posts and want to list non featured blog posts also. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not filter in the template. This is not only inefficient, but a template is *not* meant to implement *business logic*, only *rendering* logic: a template should not be concerned with *what* it renders, it should only be concerned with rendering the data in a pleasant way.

You should filter in the `ListView`:

```
class Home(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(featured=True)
```

This will filter at the *database* side.

If you need both the featured items, and the ones that are not featured, you can make two queries:

```
class Home(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(featured=True)

    def non_featured(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(featured=False)
```

then you can render the non-featured items with:

```
{% for post in view.non_featured %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Rochie: you can add extra methods to the view and use these at the template side, see edit.

Comment: That seems obvious now thanks for making me look like an idiot! However, this exactly what I needed. Ive went and implemented both featured and non_featured functions and sorted them by date. Coffee is en route